File Upload with Google Drive
So I'm creating a react application where I want to convert the users conversation into a docx file and then upload it to their Google Drive.
I am currently able to convert the chat data to docx file  with the docx npm package which returns a blob.
Then init the gapi and added a test user to test.
I am able to see the oauth consent screen but after i click allow i get redirected with a 403 error.
{error: "access_denied", error_description: "Invalid client for this origin."}
error
: 
"access_denied"
error_description
: 
"Invalid client for this origin."


I have tried enabling the correct scopes
ensured that the redirect url is correct
added the email that im using as a test user

Can you confirm if you tried adding the user in the screenshot as a test user in the Configure the OAuth consent screen and choose scopes of the Google Cloud console?
